# PHP exec date -s runs fine but does not update datetime

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, exec

Here my simple PHP file:

```
<?php
if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['datetime'])) {
        $datetime = htmlspecialchars($_POST['datetime']);
        $datetime[10] = ' ';
        $datetime = substr($datetime, 0, 19);
        die (json_encode(exec('date -s' . escapeshellarg($datetime))));
    }
}
```

here the javascript snippet that sends data:

```
function syncTime() {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.set("datetime", new Date().toISOString());

    fetch("datetime.php", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json));
        .catch(err => console.log('Request Failed', err));
}
```

The sent content is like this:

```
2023-09-08T20:49:28.696Z
```

after cleaning it up `$datetime` looks like:

```
2023-09-08 20:49:28
```

hence the executed command is:

```
date -s "2023-09-08 20:49:28"
```

the command is successfully executed because I receive back the output:

```
Fri Sep  8 20:49:28 UTC 2023
```

but checking the actual `date` on server reveals the command was not actually executed:

```
# date
Thu Jan  1 08:34:07 UTC 1970
```

But if I manually type the *very same* command above it works:

```
# date -s "2023-09-08 20:49:28"
Fri Sep  8 20:49:28 UTC 2023
# date
Fri Sep  8 20:49:28 UTC 2023
```

What is happening here?
I'm working on Linux for Raspberry Pi 3 and `apache2` is running as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the command is successfully executed because I receive back the output:
>
> ```
> Fri Sep  8 20:49:28 UTC 2023
> ```

This is not necessarily true. You can't determine success based on output. If you check the exit status of the command (by passing `$result_code` as a parameter to `exec()`), you'll likely find it to be non-zero (indicating an error).

> apache2 is running as root

This is almost certainly not true. It's running as www-data or some other non-priv user. So when it execs the script, it doesn't have permission to set the clock. However, the `date` command *still* outputs the date in this case, which is what you're seeing. If you were to capture stderr as well, you'd get:

```
date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
Fri Sep  8 08:49:28 PM EDT 2023
```

Comment: The `$result_code` is `0`. I think is running as root since: `# apachectl` returns 
`httpd (pid 289) already running` and `# ps | grep 289` returns `289 root     /usr/bin/httpd -k start`

Comment: I'm using a Buildroot environment by the way. Not Raspbian or similar.

Comment: But you're right about `stderr`: `date: can't set date: Operation not permitted`. I'm still confused...

Comment: The Apache control process runs as root. The spawned connection handlers don't. Change your command to `exec('whoami');` to find out which user it's switching to.

Comment: `daemon`, bingo! But I don't have `sudo` on my system...

Comment: Yep, well, you can't set the clock from an unprivileged account and actually running your web server as root is a big security hole. I'm confused as to why you'd ever want to set the clock from a locally hosted web form in the first place?

Comment: Long story short: the server has neither Internet connection nor RTC. Hence, when a smartphone connects to its AP it sends its own date time to the server. It's used as internal device, not exposed to public users.

Comment: Anyway, I may ask if we can add `sudo` to the available packages...

Comment: Push the date via SSH from another server? `ssh root@whatever 'date -s "2023-09-08 20:49:28"'`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78299/allow-a-specific-user-or-group-root-access-without-password-to-bin-date